# DRF changes name or ignores "create" route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm new to DRF's "viewsets", but I've inherited some problematic code, and am having trouble figuring out what's going on.  I have stripped down the code below to isolate the behavior I don't understand.

In my `urls.py` I have

```
from my_app.api import CurrentUserViewSet,
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("me", CurrentUserViewSet, basename="api-me")
print(router.urls)
```

Note the diagnostic `print` statement at the end.

The `CurrentUserViewSet` is defined as:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.views.generic import View

class CurrentUserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSetMixin, View):

    def create(self, request):
        """Update current user."""
        instance = request.user
        ...

    @action(detail=False, methods=["post"])
    def some_other_route(self, request):
        ...
```

When I start a runserver instance that uses the above, it hits my `print` statement in "urls.py" and displays this:

```
[
<URLPattern '^me/$' [name='api-me-list']>,
<URLPattern '^me\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='api-me-list']>,
<URLPattern '^me/some_other_route/$' [name='api-me-some-other-route']>,
<URLPattern '^me/some_other_route\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='api-me-some-other-route']>...
]
```

So it looks like the name of my `create` route is being changed to `list`. I don't know how or why this is happening.  Interestingly, if I define an *addtional* route that is actually named "list", the "create" method still does not appear in the URLs created by the router. It seems to be totally ignored.

As I mentioned, I inherited this code.  I *think* that even though the original author named this route "create", he was actually trying to *update* the currently authenticated user (as implied by the docstring).  I think he put his custom code in a method called "create" because he wanted to get the user from `request.user` and not retrieve it from a pk in a signature like `def update(self, request, pk=None)`.

But this doesn't seem to work because execution will never enter that `create` method. At least, I've never seen it happen.

So my questions are:

- Would the code above ever have worked, maybe in some earlier version of DRF?
- If I name a route "create", why/how does it get changed to "list"?
- If I add a route that is actually named "list", why is the "create" route ignored by `DefaultRouter` ?
- What is a better way to update the currently authenticated user that does not take a `pk` parameter, but just uses `request.user`?

Many thanks

Comment: `create` a reserved action in DRF, check this page in the docs to see how to use viewsets https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

Comment: Thank you @Jimmar - I realize it's a reserved action, but then again, so is "list". I haven't found anything that says that DRF will change the name of one reserved action to another. I'm still looking for an explanation of the described behavior and/or a better way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: The `-list` url accepts both `GET` and `POST`. If you use that URL with a `GET`, it will call `list`, while using `POST` will call `create`. It's understandable that the naming is a bit confusing, but it does make sense to use just one URL for both creating and listing. You can find the implementation of the mappings [`here`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L91) and the discussion in the docs [`here`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter)(your question is answered by the first row)